# removing error from the data read from the distance measuring sensor

Tags: python, statistics, sensors

I am using an ultrasonic sensor to read water level by using python.There are 5% chances of getting wrong value from the sensor. 5% is not a variation of value from actual value. it is actually the percentage of getting wrong value. Which causes all correct and wrong values at the same place. How can i remove that 5% error values from the data? the data sample looks like this.

45.1,45.3,45.4,45.7,46.6,47.1,47.9,48.1,48.4,48.8,49.1,49.2,49.1,46.2,45.2,45.7,45.8,43.6,45.6,44.6

These are 20 values. one (5%) out of these 20 values is wrong which i want to exclude.

Thank you!

Comment: How can you identify a "wrong" value? Is it a matter of an offset from an average value or anything like it?

Comment: If the "wrong" value isn't an outlier, then there is no reason to find it and remove it. If it is, you should consider using wavelets as  an anomaly detection technique.

Comment: There is a sump which fills up with water lets say in 5 minutes then the water is pumped out in 5 seconds and sump gets empty. Again fills up and gets empty. These cycles keep going. The aim of sensor is to keep checking the water level each 15 seconds. By taking the minimum water level value and the maximum water level value we identify one cycle. Later on we have to calculate how many cycles were done in 1 hours and so. Now the problem is sensor does not always send the accurate value. some times it sends the higher or lower values which effect the logic of calculating number of cycles.